# Hand Lettering style?

Tags: typefaces, style-identification, lettering

(not sure this type of question belongs on this forum but thought i would ask)

So I'm looking at learning a particular style of hand letter, for the life of me i cant find many other reference other than the the one attached. I'm curious as to if this style of lettering has particular name? or if anyone could point me in the right direction to find some similar inspiration?

Any help would be appreciated,

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Try browsing dafont.com or use a service like whatdafont which can be found with a Google search.

Comment: Try "thick cursive font". The vast majority of google image hits are pretty close.

Answer (score 3):

The only term I can say it is for sure is a "[script](https://www.google.com/search?q=script+font&num=20&safe=active&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT8JiF1KTLAhVDQCYKHbrxDrkQ_AUIBygB)" font.

Beyond that, it reminds me of [50's fonts](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=955&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=50s+font&oq=50s+font&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i7i30l8.7630.7630.0.7800.1.1.0.0.0.0.89.89.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.1.88.LE_nQNZSaM8) like those of [drive ins](https://www.google.com/search?q=drive+in+font&num=20&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj79Mby0aTLAhUJbiYKHd01BGsQ_AUIBygB&biw=1920&bih=955) or a [baseball team](https://www.google.com/search?q=baseball+font&num=20&safe=active&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5msuq0qTLAhVEwiYKHW9BAvkQ_AUIBygB&biw=1920&bih=955). It is kind of like the [Coca Cola](http://www.dafont.com/loki-cola.font) font, so you could look for similar fonts of that as well.

Comment: I would go for Baseball script, see related search at myFonts.com
https://www.myfonts.com/search/tag%3A%22baseball+script%22/fonts/

Comment: @Emilie: I'm not sure about the term "baseball script". For me it smells strongly of [1950s Americana](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/149533650099297343/) as well, and that may be how it ended up on baseballs (or possibly the bleechers) in the first place.

Comment: The generic name from the days when a signwriter was a person rather than a machine would be "brush script". Which is somewhat misleading, since the tool you'd use is called a *dagger* (as opposed to the much shorter and stiffer *brush*). One might also find it filed under show card fonts/letterng.